# How can I move the woocommerce checkbox to the right?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, conditional-statements

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I've tried to use some `css` which didn't work this is the `php` file. Right now the checkbox covers the first 2 letters of the sentence which displays as: e read and accept the terms & conditions * when trying to make a payment at the checkout page. Please help me with the Custom `css` at Dashboard > Appearance > Customize > Additional `CSS` in WP

```
<?php
if ( $terms_content ) {
    do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_terms_and_conditions' );
    echo '<div class="woocommerce-terms-and-conditions" style="display: none; max-height: 200px; overflow: auto;">' . $terms_content . '</div>';
}
?>
<p class="form-row terms wc-terms-and-conditions">
    <label class="woocommerce-form__label woocommerce-form__label-for-checkbox checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="woocommerce-form__input woocommerce-form__input-checkbox input-checkbox" name="terms" <?php checked( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_terms_is_checked_default', isset( $_POST\['terms'\] ) ), true ); ?> id="terms" /> <span><?php printf( __( 'I&rsquo;ve read and accept the <a href="%s" class="woocommerce-terms-and-conditions-link">terms &amp; conditions</a>', 'woocommerce' ), esc_url( wc_get_page_permalink( 'terms' ) ) ); ?></span> <span class="required">*</span>
    </label>
    <input type="hidden" name="terms-field" value="1" />
</p>
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_after_terms_and_conditions' ); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following code, it may solve your problem.

```
<?php printf( __( '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; I&rsquo;ve read and accept the <a href="%s" class="woocommerce-terms-and-conditions-link">terms &amp; conditions</a>', 'woocommerce' ), esc_url( wc_get_page_permalink( 'terms' ) ) ); ?>
```

Here I use `&nbsp;` for single space to shift the text to right.

Comment: Thanks that did the job! But is it possible to change it with some custom css? https://wordpress.org/support/topic/where-is-code-for-terms-and-conditions/#post-9374329

Comment: I know this will serve your purposes, but this is not the correct one. For the correct one I need to inspect your code via browser, if possible please share your URL.

Comment: This will do with css : .wc-terms-and-conditions .woocommerce-form__label-for-checkbox > span {
    margin-left: 20px;
}

Comment: @Samuël, expected above code will do the job. Please try that

Comment: the additional css doesn't do anything it seems like something is overriding it

Comment: Have you added that? I need to check after added that.

Comment: Yes I added it to the > Customizing > Additional CSS

Comment: See this : https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/2825985/5a8fd25f0cf2faaa6ab588e7698e3c9a Please try that by adding into the style.css, may be that css from theme options are not including into the checkout page

Comment: @Samuël, dont change any plugin file, as you update the plugin in future issue will be back.